# c fails to copy string into file

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to save a partially crypted string into a file. I have been stuck for hours now, I fail to understand where the mistake is. 
Here is the function:

```
void cryptData(string & rawTxt, string & path) {

    // the rawTxt is OK. Path is too.

    int c(0), counta(0);
    while( rawTxt[c] != '\0') { // Reading every char from the string.

        if(c <= 122) {
            // First 123 char won't be crypted. 
            // Here I do nothing to rawTxt
        }
        else { // All remaining chars will be crypted

            rawTxt[c] = cryptByte(counta, rawTxt[c]); // Replace current char at position c
                                                      // by a crypted char.
            counta++;

            if(counta > 36) // counta used for crypting,
                counta = 0;
        }
        c++;
    } 

    ofstream toDat(path.c_str() ); // Save recrypted .dat file
    toDat << rawTxt.c_str();  // HERE the first 123 chars are not copied in my file... 
}


// Crypt chars
char cryptByte(int counta, char b) {
    string plainEncryptionKey("odBearBecauseHeIsVeryGoodSiuHungIsAGo");
    b+= (char) plainEncryptionKey[counta];
    return b;
}
```

I can't understand why the 123 first chars are not saved in my file. The rawTxt string has the same length from the beginning to the end of my program. Please I'm going crazy!

Edit:
I am so, sorry, my string rawTxt is a result of a decrypted file, which has 123 random characters in the BEGINNING. So these random chars are wiped out in the decrypting algorithm. I stupidly wrote the crypting algorithm without putting these 123 chars back to where they should be.
I got the hint when I realized my code is works well with another string.
My bad. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any chance that the string contains a 0-byte? Any particular reason you are using `rawTxt.c_str()` rather than just `rawTxt`?

Comment: This code assumes that the string is null terminated (not necessarily true with an std::string.  It also assumes that the cryptByte() function will never return a null character.  Are both of these assumptions true?

Comment: You could print the first 123 characters to the output file before you start the encryption besides the problems mentioned above.

Comment: I tried both rawTxt and rawTxt.c_str(). I get the same result...

Comment: having 36 hard coded in the cryptData function ad the length of a literal string in the cryptByte function is extremely dangerous.

Comment: It may do you well do do a little char-math with the decimal [values](http://www.asciitable.com) from your string and your offset string. All your doing is adding characters together, and I doubt you're expecting what is likely undefined overflow.

Comment: Why do you cast the result of indexing plainEncryptingKey to a char?  It's already a char.

Comment: (Solved - see the edit)
Dale Wilson: Why would it be that dangerous?

Comment: WhozCraig: doesn't the compiler replace the chars by their decimal value anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.... I am just wandering about this line:

```
b+= (char) plainEncryptionKey[counta];
```

Could it be that char b goes from being a readable char (i.e. text) to an unreadable char, or somthing like a linefeed or carriadge return that overwrites the start of a line?

if you do 'a' + 'a' you don't get 'a' you get... actually I am not sure what you get, but its out of the plain text "spectrum".

Maybe you want to just check that your cryptByte is producing readable characters.... or look at your file in a binary way?

Comment: Fwiw, `a` + `a` is decimal 194 (0xc2), well outside normal printable ascii and into extended ascii-land.

Comment: I agree. There are many problems with this code, but it is writing the first 123 characters.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks!, I was too lazy to go find an ascii table :) - but I suppose the wrap-around may come into play in some cases so that the value is a "control" character from 0x00 - 0x20 or so... again, not accurate numbers!

Comment: @code_fodder assuming no value in the input string is beyond the lower printable ascii, it cannot "wrap" around. The result of two values between 0x20 and 0x127 will not exceed 0xFF. But they *can* easily exceed 0x7F (obviously) and thus light the high-bit of the `char` data value returned.

Comment: I am so, sorry, my string rawTxt is a result of a decrypted file, which has 123 random characters. I stupidly wrote the crypting algorithm without putting these 123 chars back to where they should be.
I got the hint when I realize my code is ok with another string.
My bad.

Comment: @AlexandreToque haha, no worries, so in conclusion, these characters where being written ok, but they where "garbage"?

Comment: Yes they were garbage. I am trying to write a game source code from scratch so it can be played on linux. It appears the original developers got a twisted mind crypting their character data ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile it but I got this error with -Wall and the gcc compiler :

> ‘std::ofstream toDat’ has initializer but incomplete type`

By including the **fstream** library I managed to make it work. It hope it helps. Because it it actually printing the character, if you output it in **std::cout**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify a lot using `C++11`:

```
void cryptData(string & rawTxt, string & path) {
    string plainEncryptionKey("odBearBecauseHeIsVeryGoodSiuHungIsAGo");
    int count = 0;
    for (char & c : rawTxt)
        if (c > 122) {
            c = plainEncryptionKey[count];
            count = (count + 1) % 37;
        }
    ofstream toDat(path.c_str());
    toDat << rawTxt;
}
```